# Transaction create Object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a big problem. In my model I have the following object "incident", "issue", "user". The issue has a belongsTo relationship to the incident object, and is not embedded.The user  object is an embedded object ob the issue and is also a belongsTo relationship. In my sample I want to create an issue and than set the reporter (user-object) to issue and post it to server.

I get the following error:

---

Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `loadedData` on  while in state rootState.loaded.updated.inFlight. Called with undefined

---

After post the new issue-object should be set to the incident an the incident have to update on server. 
How I solve the Problem?

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
 this._super(controller, model);
  var transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
  var issue = transaction.createRecord(App.Issue, {});
  controller.set('model', issue);
  var appController = this.controllerFor('application');
  controller.set('reporter',appController.get('user'));
}

saveIssue: function(){
   var issue = this.get('model');
   var rep = this.get('reporter');
   issue.set('reporter',rep);
   var transaction = issue.get('transaction');
     if(transaction != null){
        transaction.commit();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One difference I can see in your code that might cause the problem is that in `setupController` you are using the store's `defaultTransaction`:

```
var transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
```

but in `saveIssue` you are using the `issue` model's own transaction, which might be or not the same transaction:

```
var transaction = issue.get('transaction');
```

So my suggestion is to use the *same* transaction in both places, e.g. in `saveIssue`:

```
var transaction = this.get('store').transaction();
if(transaction != null){
  transaction.add(issue);
  transaction.commit();
}
...
```

Hope it helps.